# Time complexity of nested loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

im trying to find the worst case time complexity for the following algorithm.

```
for (i = N*N; i>1; i = i /2 ){
   for ( j = 0; j < i; j++){
   counter++;
   }
}
```

I managed to figure out that the inner loop will execute in a logarithmic fashion (backwards though, but I think that doesnt matter) But im really unsure how to approach the outer loop.

Comment: Try writing it out. j runs i times for every iteration of the outer loop. So i + (i/2 + (i/4 + (i/8...))), but i = N^2, so n^2 + (n^2 / 2 + (...))) etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @ClintPowell pointed out, the inner loop is `O(i)`.  The trick, then, is to add up the various values for `i`.

Suppose that the outer loop was `i=1; i<=K; i=i*2` (as you point out, the order doesn't matter), and solve in terms of `K`.  Then substitute `N*N` for `K`, and simplify as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well the outer loop executes for log n times and the inner loop executes i times. 
If k=log n, then summation of i from 1 to k would be k(k+1)/2,which is O(log n)^2.
Hope this helps.